# Can a unnamed function be called in R?

Tags: r

Let's assume we have the following R code at the beginning of a R script named script.R:

```
function(input) { 
 output <- input*input
 return(output)
}
```

Is there a valid way to call this unnamed function in the reminder of script.R?

Comment: My best guess - no

Comment: basically, I agree - except for this exception: Use `.Last.value(12)` right after the unnamed function.

Comment: I don't think it can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but it's not advisable. You would have to use `eval` and `parse` (or similar) to do it.

**thisfile.R**

```r
function(input) {
 output <- input*input
 return(output)
}

# This can be many lines later:
fun <- eval(parse(text = paste(readLines("thisfile.R", 4), collapse = "\n")))

# Now you can use the function.
print(sapply(1:5, fun))
```

And sourcing it gives:

```r
source("thisfile.R")
#> [1]  1  4  9 16 25
```

Not that although the function is stored as `fun` in the above example, you could use it directly, e.g.

```r
print(sapply(1:5,
  eval(parse(text = paste(readLines("thisfile.R", 4), collapse = "\n")))))
```

And of course it would no longer work if you changed the filename or moved it to a different location.